# Node.js NPM doesn't recognized -g as a command

Tags: node.js, npm, cmd, mingw-w64

[image]

NPM doesn't -g as a command there for I'm unable install anything globally.
Anyways this behavior only for the Command Prompt when I do the same in Bash

[image]

It works fine.
Why this happens?

Comment: there's probably a problem with your npm.cmd file. run `where npm` to find where your npm.cmd files are located and try to edit it to find what's wrong. Or maybe you have a mix of two different versions installed at the same time?

Comment: do you try reinstall of node.js?